# Ionic 4 Changing Image Fill Color

Tags: ionic-framework, svg, ionic3, ionic4

I am new to Ionic 4 and am trying to figure out the properties for `<ion-img>`. I am simply trying to change the image fill color of a svg file to white. Any help will be appreciated.

Home page code:  `home.page.hmtl`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
  <ion-row class  = "row1">
    <ion-img src = "/assets/icon/safety.svg"></ion-img>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Trying to change the fill color in `home.page.scss`

```
.row1{
    ion-img{
        --background-color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: With the `home.page.scss` style you could not change the background ?

Comment: @SergioEscudero I'm not understanding the question. I was unable to change the fill color of the image; however I can change the background color of the application which is not shown.

Comment: Got it. ->`--background-color: white;` why are you using these dashes?

Comment: @SergioEscudero From my research and from the variables.scss file that is the syntax used

Comment: Where did you find this ?

Comment: @SergioEscudero The variables.scss file, when I created the project it was the syntax used

Comment: Just remove those dashes. It should work

Comment: @SergioEscudero Thank you! It changed the background color, is it anyway to change the actual fill of the image?

Comment: @SergioEscudero Meaning I want the actual picture to be red not just the background.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue use

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```